# How do I output records grouped by date in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now my page looks something like this:

```
Record10, created on 02.11.11
Record9, created on 02.11.11
Record8, created on 29.10.11
Record7, created on 25.10.11
...
```

Now, what is the best way to render this way:

```
02.11.11
  Record10
  Record9
29.10.11
  Record8
25.10.11
  Record7
...
```

Another working example of what I'm trying to accomplish is SO's reputation page, where there dates and each date has 1+ actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@records.group_by{|g| g.date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") }.each do |date, record_group|
  puts date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
  record_group.each do |record|
    puts "  Record#{record.id}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use AR's group_by:

`Record.all.group_by{ |u| u.created_at.beginning_of_day }`